# How to make Siri aware of Google Chrome browser on Mac?

Tags: macos, siri

I have Google Chrome browser installed on my Mac. It's set as my default browser.

When I tell Siri:

> Siri, open browser

It launches Safari.

I tell Siri:

> Siri, open Chrome browser

It says "It doesn't look like you have an app named Chrome Browser...". But I have it installed. How to teach Siri that I have it and to launch it? I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Is your app actually called "Chrome Browser"? I just tried it with "Open Chrome" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke Siri and say any one of the following:

- Open Google Chrome app
- Open Google Chrome
- Open Chrome app
- Open Chrome
- Launch Google Chrome app
- Launch Google Chrome
- Launch Chrome app
- Launch Chrome

If some of the above doesn't work during the first try, you can alternatively, invoke Siri and say:

- Open app

or

- Launch app

[image] [image]

Siri will respond back by asking what app you wish to launch. You can simply ask to open *Google Chrome app*, *Chrome app* or simply *Chrome*. With subsequent tries, when Siri has become *aware* of the Google Chrome app, you will be able to launch Google Chrome with the commands mentioned in the beginning.